# Cross domain issue loading SVG files without "www", but updated htaccess accordingly

Tags: javascript, xml, .htaccess, security, svg

I've run into a cross policy issue with SnapSVG trying to load SVG files when I have no "www" in the URL.

I updated my htaccess file so that SVG and webfonts would have a more liberal policy, but it doesn't seem to be working if I don't include "www"

FULL HTACCCESS FILE:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz

AcceptPathInfo On


<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Looks for files and directories that do not exist
# and provide the segments to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/index.php
RewriteCond $1 !.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

ERROR IN CHROME:

```
OPTIONS http://www.adaptiveemails.com/assets/svg/computers.svg Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. snap.svg-min.js:19
d.ajax snap.svg-min.js:19
d.load snap.svg-min.js:19
window.onload (index):481
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.adaptiveemails.com/assets/svg/computers.svg. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Comment: What vhost config did you apply this to? Maybe you should look at the actual headers instead of the config?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message you are getting:

> Request header field **X-Requested-With** is not allowed by **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**.

So it doesn't seem to have anything to do with enforcing the "www", which you don't seem to have any rules in your htaccess file that does anything about that anyways. Try removing the "svg" from your access control header set container:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: No luck. I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://adaptiveemails.com' is therefore not allowed access."